# linq where clause problem on multiple join tables

Tags: linq

```
var studentDetails = from aspUser in db.aspnet_Users
join aspMembership in db.aspnet_Memberships on
    aspUser.UserId equals aspMembership.UserId
join expUser in db.explore_users on
           aspUser.UserId equals expUser.aspnetUserId
               where expUser.Id.Equals(studID)
               select new { expUser.DOB,
                            aspMembership.Email,
                            aspUser.UserName,
                            aspUser.LoweredUserName,
                            expUser.Id };

gv1.DataSource = studentDetails;
gv1.DataBind();
```

I have no idea why this did not work. When i remove where clause everything is running.
I have try to put where expUser.Id == studID is also did not work

if anyone can help me pls

Comment: What type is `Id` and what is `studID`?  Are they even matching types?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be `where expUser.aspnetUserId.Equals(studID)`?

If ID is the correct column then (as already commented) of what type are expUser.ID and the variable studID? Are they of the same type? If so then does the studID value exist in db.explore_users?

Comment: it fixed, it was my bad studID on where clause did not properly passed to the funciton.